# How to draw a round rectangle on the video with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to draw a round rectangle on the video, but I don't know how to achieve it, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** [Over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62400465/435093) there is an ffmpeg-only solution that is a little bit more complex (and CPU-intensive) than this one here.

You could use a combination of ImageMagick and ffmpeg.

Draw a rounded rectangle [using `convert`](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/):

```
convert -size 100x60 xc:transparent \
  -fill white -stroke black \
  -draw "roundrectangle 20,10 80,50 20,15" \
  rectangle.png
```

Then overlay it on the video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i rectangle.png -filter_complex overlay output.mp4
```

[image]

See the [`overlay` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) documentation for more placement options.